# IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Tags: python

Boa noite. Estou com o seguinte código em Python, mas aparece o erro citado:

```
import numpy as np 
x=np.ones((4,1)) 
for k in range (5,45): 
x[k]=5.5369*x[k-1]*(x[k-2])**2+0.1931*x[k-3] 
print(x)
```

O erro é:

> ```
> IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
> ```

Comment: O que é que você está tentando fazer com esse código?

Comment: Você está criando uma matriz 4x1 e então tentando acessá-la como se fosse um vetor nas posições de 2 até 45.

Comment: Eu já tenho as 4 primeiros valores do vetor x, então através da função recursiva dentro do for, quero calcular os outros valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem dois problemas grandes no seu código (mais uma pequena falha de formatacão dentro do loop).

Um está no seu `range`, o outro na alocacão do vetor.

- **Range**:

Para um vetor de tamanho N, Python usa indices de 0 até N-1.
No seu caso, `N=4`, com índice máximo de `N-1=3`.

A primeira chamada usa `range(5,45) = [5, 6, ... , 44]` com `k-1=4`. Obviamente um problema aí. Usando `range(4,45)`, este problema fica resolvido, mas daí temos o problema seguinte.

- **Memória**:

Em `Matlab` a sua sintaxe funciona, pois ele vai alocando a memória conforme a matrix é chamada. *Vale lembrar que isso é uma prática de programacão terrível!* 
 Não use isso ao menos que você *realmente* precise. Em Python, ele não faz isso. Pelo menos não desta maneira.

O que você quer é fazer um `append` a matrix.
Porém vamos a um código da maneira eficaz, em que o vetor foi alocado completamente antes do cálculo:

```
x=np.ones((45,1)) 
for k in range(3,45): 
  x[k]=5.5369*x[k-1]*(x[k-2])**2+0.1931*x[k-3] 

print(x)
```

Caso você queira muito usar o `append` (que não é necessário para este caso, mas pode ser para outro), o código fica:

```
x=np.ones((3,1)) 
for k in range (3,45): 
  x=np.append(x,5.5369*x[k-1]*(x[k-2])**2+0.1931*x[k-3])    
print(x)
```